# Batch Command Not Outputting with Copied Exe

Tags: batch-file, icacls

The basic situation is this.

If I call icalcs using either of these:

```
icalcs <path> /grant:r <SID>
C:/Windows/System32/icalcs <path> /grant:r <SID>
```

I get a result of:

```
processed file: <path>
Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files
```

If I call icalcs from a place where I've copied the exe to, it doesn't output anything.

For example:

```
C:/Test/icalcs <path> /grant:r <SID>
```

What causes this?

I have a perl script that runs icalcs to modify an NTFS fileshare. I cannot rely on icalcs to be available on the same system as the perl script so I have to package it with it.

Comment: You're doing it wrong. Use `%SystemRoot%\System\icacls.exe` and let Windows figure out where it's installed and whether it needs to run the 32 or 64 bit version of the executable, and then you don't have to distribute it. (You shouldn't be distributing system files anyway; it violates MS software license and good practices, as well as often causing problems with AV and malware apps.)

Comment: How do I make the perl script OS-independent (without copying the exe) if it depends on icacls to modify the NTFS permissions of a fileshare?

Comment: icacls is already Windows-dependent. If your script is not running on Windows, then the icacls executable won't run anyway. IOW, it's already OS-dependent.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. You are right. Still curious why it doesn't output anything though.

Comment: What happens if you change to that directory and manually (not through your script). try to run the same command from there?

Comment: The output is ignored regardless of whether it's called from Perl or CMD. I also navigated directly to the exe via CD and used an absolute path in CMD.

Comment: Then it's quite possible that Windows simply isn't allowing it to run because it's a system file and isn't being run from the proper location. One more reason for not trying to redistribute system files. :-)

Comment: It runs successfully. It just doesn't output anything.